# Why do We differentiate doubly?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, analytic-geometry

The differential equation of all the ellipses centered at the origin is

---

$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1,$ after differentiating w.r.t $x,$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{2 x}{a^{2}}+\frac{2 y y^{\prime}}{b^{2}}=0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{y y^{\prime}}{b^{2}}=-\frac{x}{a^{2}}$

$\Leftrightarrow \frac{\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}}{b^{2}}+\frac{y\left(y^{\prime \prime}\right)}{b^{2}}=-\frac{1}{a^{2}}$

$\Leftrightarrow\left(y^{\prime}\right)^{2}+y\left(y^{\prime \prime}\right)^{2}=-\frac{b^{2}}{a^{2}}$

Comment: Because there are two parameters !

Comment: to make it 0 right?

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by $x^2$,

$$\frac1{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2x^2}=\frac1{x^2}$$ and after differentiation,

$$\frac{2xyy'-2y^2}{b^2x^3}=-\frac2{x^3}.$$

Then

$$xyy'-y^2=-b^2$$ gives

$$xy'^2+xyy''-yy'=0.$$

---

A more systematic way is to differentiate the initial equation twice and express that you get a compatible system in $\dfrac1{a^2},\dfrac1{b^2}$:

$$\begin{vmatrix}x^2&y^2&-1\\2x&2yy'&0\\2&2y'^2+2yy''&0\end{vmatrix}=0.$$

Comment: +1.Just a short comment: what is the mathematical usefulness of differentiating an ellipse? I think: what it can be useful for? Thank you.

Comment: @Sebastiano: this is essentially for the understanding of ODE's and families of curves.

Comment: Thank you very much....but I have ask a specific question because I have not understood the significance. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756969/importance-of-the-mathematical-differentiating-an-ellipse-or-of-a-conic

Answer (score 0):

The true reason might be found in the context before or after the equations that you have put in your post. Already after one differentiation we have an ordinary differential equation (ODE) for half-ellipses. But all the solutions have their center at origin. By eliminating $x$ through a second differentiation the resulting differential equation will also cover solutions have their center at other points on the $x$-axis. Thus we get an ODE with a larger family of solutions.