# Importance of the mathematical differentiating of an ellipse (or of a conic)?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, proof-explanation, analytic-geometry, conic-sections, intuition

Supposing to have a canonical ellipse (or other conics, parabola, circle, or hyperbola):

$$\frac{x^{2}}{a^{2}}+\frac{y^{2}}{b^{2}}=1, \quad \text{or} \quad \frac{(x-x_0)^2}{a^{2}}+\frac{(y-y_0)^2}{b^{2}}=1$$

What is the  meaning of the differentiating an ellipse for the ODE?

Related: [Why do We differentiate doubly?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3756678/why-do-we-differentiate-doubly/3756687?noredirect=1#comment7727428_3756687)

PS: **I ask this question for students of an high school.**

Comment: @YvesDaoust If there is something useful, practical or concrete for high school students when I draw differential equations.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If the differentiation of any conic can have physical meanings contained in the integral lines and what is their usefulness to differentiate the conics. Related you comment: this is essentially for the understanding of ODE's and families of curves.

Comment: @YvesDaoust If there's any correlation between mathematics and physics in my question. I was wondering why I need to differentiate an ellipse. What do I need it for?

Comment: You don't need it.

Comment: @Sebastiano: When setting up differential equations describing the motion of bodies, you usually end up with equations of second order.
So, it is quite useful to know the 2nd order differential equations of ( for example) conic sections to recognize them and, hence, to know what path the motion follows.

Comment: @trancelocation Can you put a nice answer? Just to implement my knownledge. Tks.